# Any code for updating the distance when my current location is moved in google map

Tags: java, android, dictionary, location

I can find the distance between the current location and the nearby place but I can't update the distance when I'm moving. Is there any code to update the distance?

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the LocationListener

```
public class mLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // add your code here to run when location changed
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

you can set when to execute the code by either time limit or a minimum distance

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationListener listener= new mLocationListener ();
if (locationManager != null) {
    locationManager .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, mintime, mindistance, listener);
}
```

for more details Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener

Update : mintime should be long and mindistance should be float

about request location function
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)

Comment: I have done what u said, but after adding 
 locationManager.requeslocationUpdates,it shows error like 'Cannot resolve method 'requestLoactionUpdates(java.lang.String,int,int,com.example.map.Main.mLocationListener)' '

Comment: @CharlVictor answer updated. define mintime as long and mindistance as float